# RestfulRouting Routing Library for MVC - Problems with Routes - Weirdness

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use this RestfulRouting framework we have in place...a 3rd party framework found here:  `http://stevehodgkiss.github.com/restful-routing/`

I can't figure out for the life of me why I'm getting a list of routes that just doesn't seem what I'd expect.  I've read that one page documentation (which to me is nice but lacking) and still I get routes generated that seem to come out of nowhere for certain actions I did or did not define.

For instance, here's one I setup:

public class Routes : RouteSet
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        routes.MapRoutes();
    }

```
public override void Map(IMapper map)
{

    map.Resources<CarController>(cars =>
    {
        cars.As("Cars");
        cars.Collection(x =>
        {
            //x.Get("Edit");
            x.Post("Update");
            x.Get("Delete");
        });
    });
```

}

My controller for Cars looks like this (skeleton / top level view I'm giving you here):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OurCompanyName.Web.Controllers.WebApp
{

    public class CarController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(string carId)
        {
           // logic
        }


        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            // logic
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(FormCollection formCollection, int id = 0)
        {
        // logic
        }


        public ActionResult CarTypes()
        {
            // logic
        }


        public ActionResult New()
        {
            // logic
        }


        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            // logic
        }
    }
```

}

But when I look at this framework's debug tool (i.e. http://localhost/routedebug) on my machine or our dev server, it's spitting out some weirdness and here are the routes that generated when I look at them through the debug tool:

[image]

So where are all these duplicate (like delete and update showing 2 different ways/entries) and where did or how did Cars/{id}/Edit path become generated here from this framework?

Ultimately I'd like to also have Cars/{id}/Delete but I cannot get that configured no matter what I try with this framework.

I don't understand where the name and endpoint come in...what is using that?  When I used MVC, it only cares about the routes I set up, not some [name]#[name].  I realize it's probably proprietaryto this framework but I can't find any documentation on a lot of this and why it's spitting out a bunch of default routes that I won't even use or use in that convention.

for example I have no need to use these routes/conventions that this thing generated:

219     POST        Cars    cars#create

for me I'd probably want to see Cars/Create/{id} or Cars/{id}/Create.  If you are going with a RESTful convention IMO it should be Cars/Create/{id} where {id} is at the end...but that's another topic or observation outside my question here...and for now I'm going with the team's standard which is to do Controller/{id}/Action if there is an id involved.

Summary:  ultimately I'm asking how the heck this is working and second, how can I get my Cars/{id}/Delete route established here with this framework?

Answer (score 1):

The resources method generates 7 crud routes for the controller (the bottom 7 in your debug output)- index, show, new, edit, update, create, destroy. You can adjust the routes generated with `cars.Only("index", "create")` or `cars.Except("destroy")`.

The endpoint is what the route is hooked up to, controller#action.

To get your delete link working use Member:

```
cars.Member(x =>
{
    x.Get("Delete");
}
```

If you want routes like `Cars/Create/{id}` then I suggest that you don't use restful-routing. Or you could ask your team why they are using it?

Comment: Yea I kinda get all that from just reviewing stuff.  But how did we get the /Controller/{id}/action in there for the edit??  I do not see any regular mvc routes defined or any in your framework.  It's gotta come from somewhere.  Also how is controller/action/{id} not restful?  To me it seems like it would be http://wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture/

Comment: And I've tried the x.Get("Delete") and no matter what I do (decorate the delete action with HttpPost or HttpDelete, or no Http attribute at all, it doesn't hit it).  And again, we want Controller/{id}/Delete or Controller/Delete/{id} so why wouldn't your framework support such a common usage in MVC?  I don't get it.

Comment: so what is this .Member as compared to .Collection?  We're using all .Collection from your framework.  I see absolutely no .Member in our routes all using your framework and somehow we're still able to get Controller/{id}/Edit for example to show up in your route tool.  Again we are not using the MVC out of box routing so how is this being generated from your framework?

Comment: so basically, your resources creates 7 default routes.  Then if you use a collection, it creates additional routes.  So with my Delete and Update items in .Collection, that's why I'm getting the top two additional routes in my grid above...I assume.

Comment: Finally where is this Name coming from? Example new_car, edit_car when the rest don't have a name?  What's that all about?

Comment: The controller/{id}/edit route is one of the default routes generated by Resources. If you want to be able to post or delete to controller/{id}/delete, use .Delete("delete") or .Post("delete") inside Member. Member generates routes with an ID, so controller/{id}/route. Collection generates routes on the controller, so controller/route. The name is automatically generated, you can use it for named routes or just ignore it.